# Using "args" but method still not taking more than one array as parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, args

I want to make a method that takes x amount of `ArrayList<>` as a parameter. When I use args this does not work. Is args only reserved for int and String etc? Why does not args become a new array containing my arraylist? I thought there was a way to be able to give multiple parameter values to a method that turns into an array inside the method?

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArraytList();
list1.add("1");
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add("2");
list2.add("3");
```

A print method:

```
public void print(ArrayList<String> args){
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < args[i].size(); j ++){
            System.out.println(args[i].get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Does not work

Comment: That's because you're trying to pass two arraylists into your method when it will only accept one.

Comment: Yeah, your printElements takes only one parameter but you are passing two.

Comment: Also, I am assuming you're using lambda expression to make your code shorter and more concise? in that case you can reduce your lambda expression to this ----->  args.forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: When you use lambda and foreach like that - and want to change something to all the elemnts, that variable or whatever it is has to be declared outside the method, which I think usally becomes more messy. So I usally stick with for loops at all times. But yes that would have maken it this shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printElements` takes a single parameter of type `ArrayList<String>`, but you're trying to give it two arguments of type `ArrayList`.

Comment: If I would do `printElements(String args)`, that would take more than one String as paramater - and args is an array. I would like to have a parameter taking in x amount of arrays and turn them into a nested array (args) - just the same way.

Comment: @Lealo no. That would take a single array as a parameter. If you want to take any number of `ArrayList<String>` parameters, then set the type of ages to `ArrayList<String>...` or ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: The `ArrayList<String> ... args` was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
first.addAll(second);
printElements(first);
```

Comment: `addAll` returns a `boolean`, not a new list.

Comment: sorry my bad. updated it. thanks @JoeC for the correction